# Python pytube calculate download speed and elapsed time

Tags: python, pytube

So i have a download callback function

```
def downloadCallback(stream, chunk, file_handle, bytes_remaining):
    fileSize = stream.filesize
    bytes_downloaded = fileSize - bytes_remaining
    percentage = round((bytes_downloaded / fileSize) * 100, 2)
    print(f"{percentage}% Downloaded", end="\r")
```

So far I have been able to get the percentage. but no luck when it comes to getting the download speed and elapsed time.

This callback is being called continuously on this code

```
yt = YouTube(link, on_progress_callback=downloadCallback)
streamVideo = yt.streams.first()
streamVideo.download()
```

Feel free to mark this as duplicate because I've also seen a lot of questions regarding this problem. But most of them is just confusing. I actually want someone that would explain the formula to me in layman's term

Comment: before calling set time1 to current timestamp, after it’s finished set time2 to current timestamp, and then just substract time2 - time1?

Comment: I want it to constantly update, therefore i have to do the elapsed time calculation inside the callback. Problem is it's being called way too fast. Adding a time.sleep just makes the percentage inaccurate.

Comment: do it every time you call it then

Answer (score 0):

This method is very simple and will not give exact values, but it is quite close.

You must first take the time value before starting the download.

Then in the function "downloadCallback" you return to take the value of time. Subtracting this value from the value taken before starting the download, we will have the elapsed time since the start of the download.

Now we can calculate download speed, simply by dividing the number of bytes downloaded by the elapsed time. If you want the value in Mega bytes, you must divide by 1024 twice.

To calculate the remaining time, just divide the bytes remaining to be downloaded by the speed:

```
    from pytube import YouTube
    from datetime import datetime

    download_start_time = datetime.now()

    def downloadCallback(stream, chunk, bytes_remaining):
        global download_start_time
        seconds_since_download_start = (datetime.now()-        download_start_time).total_seconds()    
        total_size = stream.filesize
        bytes_downloaded = total_size - bytes_remaining
        percentage_of_completion = bytes_downloaded / total_size * 100
        speed = round(((bytes_downloaded / 1024) / 1024) / seconds_since_download_start, 2)    
        seconds_left = round(((bytes_remaining / 1024) / 1024) / float(speed), 2)
        print("percentage_of_completion:", round(percentage_of_completion, 2), "%")
        print("seconds_since_download_start:", round(seconds_since_download_start, 2), "seconds")
        print("speed:", round(speed, 2), "Mbps")
        print("seconds_left:", round(seconds_left, 2), "seconds")
        print()


    def main():
        global download_start_time
        chunk_size = 1024
        url = "https://youtu.be/BBnomwpF_uY"
        yt = YouTube(url)
        video = yt.streams.get_highest_resolution()
        yt.register_on_progress_callback(downloadCallback)
        print(f"Fetching \"{video.title}\"..")
        print(f"Fetching successful\n")
        print(f"Information: \n"
              f"File size: {round(video.filesize * 0.000001, 2)} MegaBytes\n"
              f"Highest Resolution: {video.resolution}\n"
              f"Author: {yt.author}")
        print("Views: {:,}\n".format(yt.views))

        print(f"Downloading \"{video.title}\"..")

        download_start_time = datetime.now()
        video.download()

    main()
```